# How to set same colors in jtable and set different colors to different result in java

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans, jtable

I'm trying to search old invoice data from invoice table. And when I search the invoices issued to same customer I want to set same color to the purchased item in same invoice ID. This is something I took from internet.

[image: Table]

As an example if I purchased 3 different item from same invoice ID I want to color red (or any color I'm suggesting) those rows in jtable. And one customer usually can buy items in at least 50 different invoices. So there are 50 different invoice IDs.

So I'm hoping color should change in a mathematical order. I have searched internet related to this problem. Since I'm new to java I couldn't understand about it very well.

**new Upload**
[image]

Comment: Rendering of cells comes down to the `TableCellRenderer`, have a look at [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer). You could also consider the highlighting support of `JXTable` in SwingX libraries

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample code using [DefaultTableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html).

- selected row in green color
- even row in cyan color
- old row in light gray color

Sample code:

```
Object[] columnNames = { "A", "B", "C" };
Object[][] data = { { "abc", new Double(850.503), 53 }, { "lmn", new Double(36.23254), 6 },
        { "pqr", new Double(8.3), 7 }, { "xyz", new Double(246.0943), 23 } };

JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

MyCustomTableCellRenderer cellRenderer = new MyCustomTableCellRenderer();
for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);
}
```

CustomTableCellRenderer:

```
class MyCustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object obj, boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, obj, isSelected, hasFocus, row,
                column);
        if (isSelected) {
            cell.setBackground(Color.green);
        } else {
            if (row % 2 == 0) {
                cell.setBackground(Color.cyan);
            } else {
                cell.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            }
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is so clear. Thank you. Still can you please add comment to these cord lines . Please... I added another picture please take a look at that. I understand the color settling when " row % 2 == 0 " . Still I want to put same color all same color for same inid.. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you would need to create a Map that contains the ID and the render color for that ID.

> So I'm hoping color should change in a mathematical order

Maybe you can change the color by changing the "hue" of an HSL Color. See [HSL Color](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/hsl-color/) for a class that will allow you to use HSL color and modify the "hue" easily.

> I want to set same color to the purchased item in same invoice ID.

Then to render each row you can check out [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for one approach that will allow you to render each row based of the ID of the row. Once you determine the ID for the row you get the rendering color from the Map.

Comment: You understood my situation.. Thank you so much.. :)

Comment: Could you please take a look at that uploaded photo. I want to put same color in same inid.

Comment: The link I gave you shows working examples on how to color the entire row based on a value in the row.

Comment: I went that link. :( but it download whole cord bundle. I can't find which one for which example

Comment: `but it download whole cord bundle.` - no idea what that means. You would look at the example from the "Data" tab. That example looks at the data in the "Type" column to determine how to color the row. In your case you would look at the data in your "Id" column. I can't explain the concept any clearer since I provided a working example.